# DDR pin swaping why D0, D8, D16, D24, D32, D40, D48, and D56 are fixed

Tags: ddr, ddr3

Below image is taken from [Hardware Development Guide
for i.MX 6SoloLite
Applications Processors.](https://www.nxp.com/webapp/sps/download/preDownload.jsp?render=true)

You can see that in each byte lane first and last bit are fixed.You are not allowed to swap.

May I know why is it like that.
[image]

Comment: Presumably this is explained in the referenced document JESD79-3E.

Comment: The least significant data bit is used for read / write leveling to automatically adjust the timing parameters for each byte. DQ0 for each end of the link per byte is reserved for this purpose.

Comment: I just tried to look at [DDR3 SDRAM STANDARD](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/jesd-79-3d) using my free JEDEC account, but you have purchase that standard or be a _Paying JEDEC Member_ to access it.